# How to set breakpoint in someone else's internal method in monodevelop

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop, private, breakpoints

I'm using MonoDevelop to debug some MonoGame samples that fail to work properly.

I have this issue that I can open public MonoGame classes in MonoDevelop and set breakpoints there, but I can't figure out how to set breakpoints in non-public/internal classes and methods. I can see their source in Assembly Browser but there's no way to set a breakpoint. I've tried to set breakpoint manually by class/method name but that doesn't work. Hirring F12 on desired method lands me in Assembly Browser.

How do I peek around libraries, in short?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to achieve this is by installing the Reflector plugin for VS.

This will not only allow you to "peek" in, but also decompile and set breakpoints in 3rd party libraries.

Be aware that if libraries are obfuscated then you might run into issues.